# Not getting value from Chrome Sync Save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I Created Extension, that change specific website,s background color by selection in Options. It doesn't work. I press save and navigate to page. But background color stays same. When i tried set color without chrome sync value, it worked. So, the problem is, Chrome Sync Storage Store and Get is not Working.

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "author": "Developer From Jokela",
  "name": "Edison Laajennus",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "http://rmhtmlkoodaaja.github.io/edisonplugin/",
  "short_name": "Edison Plugin",
  "permissions": 
  [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
   "https://app.edison.fi/*"
     ],
     "options_page": "asetukset/asetukset.html",
     "options_ui": {
      "chrome_style": true,
      "page": "options.html"
    },

  "background": {
    "scripts": 
    ["background.js"],

    "persistent": false
    },

"icons":
{
   "128": "images/icon128.png",
   "16": "images/icon16.png",
   "48": "images/icon48.png"
},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Edison Lajennus"
}
}
```

My Backgound.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "/welcome/welcome.html"}, function (tab) {
      console.log("Install Complete Page");
  });
});
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
  var url = tabs[0].url;
});
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': ('http://edison.fi')}, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
  });
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete')
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"bgcode.js"});
  });
var contextMenuItem = {
  "id": "opendesktop",
  "title": "Edison Työpöytä"
}
 var contextMenuItem1 = {
  "id": "savetodocs",
  "title": "Luo Uusi Asiakirja Docsiin",
  "contexts":["selection"]

 }
 var contextMenuItem2 = {
  "id": "savetoslides",
  "title": "Luo Uusi Diaesitys Slidesiin",
  "contexts":["selection"]

 }
 var contextMenuItem3 = {
  "id": "changedesktopcolor",
  "title": "Vaihda Taustan Väriä",

 }
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem1);
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem2);
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem3);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(savetodocs) {
  if (savetodocs.menuItemId == "savetodocs") {
     chrome.tabs.create({'url': ('https://docs.google.com/document/create')}, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
  });
  }
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(savetoslides) {
    if (savetoslides.menuItemId == "savetoslides") {
       chrome.tabs.create({'url': ('https://docs.google.com/presentation/create')}, function(tab) {
      // Tab opened.
    });
    }


});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(openedison) {
  if (openedison.menuItemId == "opendesktop") {
     chrome.tabs.create({'url': ('https://edison.fi')}, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
  });
  }


});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(changebgcolor) {
  if (changebgcolor.menuItemId == "changedesktopcolor") {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: 'thecode.js'
    });
  }


});
```

My options.js

```
$(function(){
    $('#saveLimit').click(function(){
    var limit = $('#limit').val();
    var save = {};
    save[item] = null;
    chrome.storage.sync.set(save)

    });
});
```

My options.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>  Edison Työpöydän Taustaväri </title>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Vaihda Edison Ty&ouml;p&ouml;yd&auml;n V&auml;ri&auml;</h1>
<br>
<br>
<input type="color" id="limit" onchange="clickColor(0, -1, -1, 5)" value="#ff0000" style="width:85%;">
<input type="submit" id="saveLimit" value="Tallenna">
</body>


</html>
```

My bgcode.js

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(save)
document.body.style.backgroundColor=save
```

Comment: You're not using the `get` function correctly. You're supposed to pass in a string or array of strings and a callback function. You can find out more about it from the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)

Comment: I used Google's example in Documentation. It's now working perfectly.